# Jump/scroll to #id within a scroll element

Tags: javascript, html

I know we can easily jump to specific ID using #hash in URL, but my problem is, the ID is within a scroll element.

My HTML structure is:

```
<body>
  <div style="height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;">  //start of scrollbox
    <div id="main1"></div>
    ...
    ... <!-- Another elements in between -->
    ...
    <div id="main30></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

id="main30" is far above in the scroll box. How to jump there? Thank you.